# How do you modify 3D object's shape (vertices) like changing a part of its height or length, adding a hole by programming

Tags: 3d, geometry

I want to know how you can achieve modifying 3D object's shape (vertices) and creating a new shape, like let's say changing a part of its height or making a hole on it by programming with a user's interaction like a mouse movement. I put the tag WebGl but I want to know general ideas how to achieve it in a 3d world.

If you don't get what I talk about it, please refer to [tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/). You can modify 3D object's shape with it.

I have no clue how it's achieved, so any info for it would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
This [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72036/in-unity-how-do-i-dynamically-manipulate-parts-of-a-mesh) is similar to mine. But the answers cannot achieve to cut a shape or such stuff, I think.

**EDIT2:**
OK, so I get an idea from the [AutoDesk](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-84591B48-71B9-4258-B287-CD2391C946D2-htm.html) doc below for changing a shape. To change a shape by moving a point or edge, I need to let a user pick either one of them then change its coordinates as the user moves their mouse.

To [cut or clip](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-dynamically-slice-a-convex-shape--gamedev-14479) a shape, I guess I need to split or create triangles where intersections happen with other shapes for achieving the same feature which tinkerpad has.

Comment: Read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/3d_computer_graphics.htm and the next page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/3d_transformation.htm

Comment: No this is not what I'm asking. I know how to transform the model. I understand the basic of how 3d computer graphics work. What I want to know is how to modify shape (vertices) by programming.

Comment: so you need [CSG constructive solid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) (there are libs for such things out there) or just an **Mesh editor** or some kind of **modifiable surface** or even **Voxel map**?  Those 4 are very different things and without knowing the purpose or your **shape** or its internal representations we can only guess

Comment: As I answered my question 2 days ago, what I was looking for was CSG. Thanks anyway @Spektre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is Constructive solid geometry.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry

I haven't yet found a good resource to understand how it's achieved behind a scene but I now know where to look at.

Comment: Yeah, I found this library as well. I might try to dig into its source code to understand how it works. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve need mastering several kind of knowledges. I think you guessed that the answer to your question may take a whole book. So I will simply try to lead you to the proper tools and concepts.

First you have to separate three different things:

- The user interaction management, so to say : How to convert mouse cursor position and movment (which is in 2D) to properly use it in the 3D world.
- The vertices attributes (position, normal, etc.) modification, which is probably the most easy part.
- The interactive mesh structure modification, here, we enter in a domain, way more complex than the two firsts.

### For user input

You have to implement what is called "Mouse Picking". You have to understands the 3D projection concept (perspective and orthographic), and then, the way to "unproject" the 2D mouse cursor position from screen to the 3D world.

For this, you will find some information here: [Mouse Picking with Ray Casting](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html)

Once you implemented this, you need a powerful algorithme to fastly detect the "ray" and mesh polygons intersection, so you can know which triangle is hit, at what position, etc.

For this, you will need to implement at least this:[Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm)

To detect raycast on vertices, you can implement an Ray-Sphere interscetion test, assuming each vertex is represented by a virtual bounding sphere with a small radius.

### For vertices/edges attributes changes

This part is easy, as you already found, you just have to adapt the vertex parameters according mouse cursor moves.

### For mesh structure modification

Here you must implement what is not so commonly implemented in 3D engines, since common 3D engines mainly work with fixed-structure mesh. But if you want to easily edit a mesh structure, removing vertices, edges, splits polygons, etc. You need a dynamic mesh data structure.

For this purpose, it exists the DCEL ( doubly connected edge list ) data structure. 
Here is the wikipedia overview: [Doubly connected edge list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list)

And here is some data to understand the concept, then implementing it:

[DCEL - Notes from the book by de Berg, Van Krevald, Overmars, and Schwarzkpf](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~binay/813.2011/DCEL.pdf)

[The DCEL Data Structure for 3D Graphics by Ryan Holmes](http://www.holmes3d.net/graphics/dcel/)

[The DCEL data structure: a C++ implementation](http://www.leonardofischer.com/dcel-data-structure-c-plus-plus-implementation/)

### Finally

To put all these thing together, you will need to understand 3D transformations, how vectors works, how to pass from one coordinate space to another by transforming vectors, coordinates, etc. by inverse matrices, etc.

Good luck !

Comment: Although your answer didn't give me an exact answer for CSG, the DCEL info gives me some insights how to implement for it. Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Those who don't understand well the first two things Sedenion mentioned, I'll recommend to read "3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development, 2nd Edition" and "Game Physics Cookbook".